# How do I Set Up my Edimax BR-6428nS Wireless Router

Tags: wireless, broadband, router

I have looked into Ask Ubuntu but I can't find an answer of the Edimax BR-6428nS model.  You can download a source code in a zip file but I do not know how to open the source code file or how to run the source code once I've opened it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you have just bought the router and are trying to set it up. You do not need the source code you downloaded, it is already installed on the router. They just make it available so that they are complying with the open source licensing.

1. Connect your computer to the router using an ethernet cable, you should have got one in the box.
2. Open a web browser. Probably firefox.
3. Type '192.168.2.1' in the address bar and press enter.
4. The user is 'admin' and the password is '1234'. Click enter.

You are now connected to the router and need to enter all the correct settings depending on your ISP and connection type. The best thing to do is (on a computer with a working internet connection) google something like 'ISP router settings' where ISP is the name of your ISP. When you have the details you can follow [this guide](http://www.edimax.co.uk/images/Image/manual/Wireless/BR-6428Ns/BR-6428nS_User_Manual.pdf) from page 24.

Answer (score 0):

To unzip any `.zip` file in Ubuntu, right click the file and select 'Extract here'.

Please, do not download the source code. You don't need it.

For setting up, just read the manual, and if you have any specific questions, do not hesitate to ask.

[User Manual](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/manual/Wireless/BR-6428nS/BR-6428nS_User_Manual.zip)

[Quick setup guide](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/QIG/Wireless/BR-6428nS/BR-6428nS_QIG_EN.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the mac address and everything but the computer itself could not detect the wireless connection.  I even lost the the wired connection and had to phone Virgin Media to get back online.  Wi-Fi does work on my notebook so the problem is the setup.

My Gmail email account defaults sometimes to my Google Mail account which has caused Ask Ubuntu create a second account. This is because Virgin Media use Google Mail and Google have linked these two account together (My Virgin Media email account and my Gmail Account)